# I am having troubles with Mysql - "about query logging issue"?

Tags: mysql, linux, database, macos, backup

i want to save the queries of my mysql to a .out/.log/.txt file on my desktop. I am using a Mac machine. i saw my friend use "tee" linux command in mysql to log the queries like

```
tee ~/Desktop/mylog.txt
```

above command worked on his laptop running windows but shows an error-

```
( Can't create/write to file '~/Desktop/mylog.txt' (Errcode: 2 - No such file or directory)
Error logging to file '~/Desktop/mylog.txt')
```

on my laptop. Once i tried with no file on my desktop to let it create one, then i pre-created one. but in both cases it was not working.

then i also tried this one below:-

```
mysqld --log=~/Desktop/myquery.log
```

this also doest work and gives an error:

```
mysqld: Can't change dir to '/usr/local/mysql-5.7.18-macos10.12-x86_64/data/' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
2017-09-05T08:35:50.566311Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2017-09-05T08:35:50.567503Z 0 [Note] --secure-file-priv is set to NULL. Operations related to importing and exporting data are disabled
2017-09-05T08:35:50.567630Z 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.7.18) starting as process 25981 ...
2017-09-05T08:35:50.602972Z 0 [Warning] Can't create test file /usr/local/mysql-5.7.18-macos10.12-x86_64/data/Lohitakshs-MacBook-Air.lower-test
2017-09-05T08:35:50.603050Z 0 [Warning] Can't create test file /usr/local/mysql-5.7.18-macos10.12-x86_64/data/Lohitakshs-MacBook-Air.lower-test
2017-09-05T08:35:50.603305Z 0 [ERROR] failed to set datadir to /usr/local/mysql-5.7.18-macos10.12-x86_64/data/
2017-09-05T08:35:50.603328Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting

2017-09-05T08:35:50.606324Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2017-09-05T08:35:50.608285Z 0 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

Then i also tried by going *SUDO*  , but that also gave the same error.

Now my problem is that i have too many queries on my screen right now, which i cannot afford to loose, so i need a solution which can solve the issue on my running server.

Thanks a lot

Comment: It doesn't understand the `~` shorthand, type the full pathname: `tee /Users/yourusername/Desktop/mylog.txt`

Comment: @Barmar  cd ~ will always put you in your home directory

Comment: @Barmar your solution worked, thanks, i think now i understand my error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mysql` program doesn't understand the `~` shorthand for your home directory.

If you're in your home directory when you run the `mysql` command, you can simply type

```
mysql> tee Desktop/mylog.txt
```

If not, you'll need to type the full path.

```
mysql> tee /Users/yourusername/Desktop/mylog.txt
```

Comment: Thanks @Barmar can you also tell how to stop that logging when needed?

Comment: Use the `notee` command. Don't you see that in the `help` output?